# TwinCAT 3.1 Timeout on Hardware scan using EL6731 rev25 and CX9020

Tags: plc, twincat

I am experiencing timeouts when scanning the hardware in a TwinCAT 3.1 project, when a [EL6731 rev25](http://www.beckhoff.at/default.asp?ethercat/el6731.htm) profibus master is used. Removing the EL6731 solves the problem, also earlier revisions of EL6731 (e.g. rev22) are working fine.

The TwinCAT project is running on a CX9020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was an update of the CX9020 image. Using Version  CX9020_CB3011_WEC7_HPS_v602j_TC31_B4018.16 (to be found [here](http://ftp.beckhoff.com/download/Software/embPC-Control/CX90xx/CX9020/CE/TC3)) everything works fine.

According to Beckhoff support in this revision a different processor is used in the EL6731.